# OdbcConnection turns DATE column into STRING?

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

UPDATE: this happens with OdbcConnection but goes away with SqlConnection. Is there any way to read a "date" via OdbcConnection?

I have a Sql Server database table with a "date" and a "datetime" column. Whenever I use C# ODBC, it returns the Date column as a string. But I would rather it return the Date as a DateTime. Is there any way to make that happen?

```
 string sql = "select dateColumn, dateTimeColumn from Test_Table";
 string dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server={...};Database=...;Trusted_Connection=True;";
 using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConfigManager.GetLoansDatabaseDSN()))
 {
         conn.Open();
         OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand()
         {
             Connection = conn,
             CommandText = sql
         };
         using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
         {
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             adapter.Fill(ds);
             DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
             //The type of "dateColumn" is now string not DateTime
          }
  }
```

Comment: Are you restricted to using an `OdbcConnection`? Can you use a `SqlConnection` or `OleDbConnection` instead?

Comment: Yes, as a test, I tried switching to SqlConnection instead of OdbcConnection. That does seem to resolve it. But I really wish we could use OdbcConnection.

Comment: Why do you want to use an `OdbcConnection`? It only provides basic support for SQL Server and no support for newer SQL Types like datetime2.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution here?  What was it?

Comment: Unfortuantly, no, I never found any solution other than switching from odbcConnection to SqlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

One of two ways.

1. Cast your dateColumn to a DateTime

   1. `string sql = "select Convert(DateTime, dateColumn) as dateColumn, dateTimeColumn from Test_Table";`
2. Build your DataTable manually to include the columns type.